# How to merge 2 Regionplots?

Tags: plotting, regions

```
tt1=RegionPlot[Sum[EuclideanDistance[{x,y},pt],{pt,CirclePoints[{0,1},
{1.5,0Degree},4]}]<=7,{x,-16,16},{y,-.5,1}];
tt2=RegionPlot[Sum[EuclideanDistance[{x,y},pt],{pt,CirclePoints[{0,-1},
{1.5,0Degree},4]}]<=7 Or RegionPlot[Sum[EuclideanDistance[{x,y},pt],
{pt,CirclePoints[{0,1},{1.5,0Degree},4]}]<=7,,{x,-6,6},{y,-1,.5}];
Show[tt1,tt2,PlotRange->All]
```

I got result as below:

[image: result]

You can find there's intersection of `tt1` and `tt2`.Actualy I want result as below:

[image: preferred result]

I tried to use `Or` in script,

```
RegionPlot[Sum[EuclideanDistance[{x,y},pt],{pt,CirclePoints[{0,-1},
{1.5,0Degree},4]}]<=7 Or Sum[EuclideanDistance[{x,y},pt],
{pt,CirclePoints[{0,1},{1.5,0Degree},4]}]<=7,{x,-6,6},{y,-6,6}]
```

But I didn't get result.
How to merge `RegionPlot`s? I raise this question because I want to get a general method.

Comment: You used `Or[]` (`||`) wrong. Try this: `RegionPlot[Sum[EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, pt], {pt, CirclePoints[{0, 1}, {1.5, 0 Degree}, 4]}] <= 7 || Sum[EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, pt], {pt, CirclePoints[{0, -1}, {1.5, 0 Degree}, 4]}] <= 7, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`

Comment: @J.M. You are right, should I close this question?

Comment: Or using Infix notation `RegionPlot[(Sum[
     EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, pt], {pt, 
      CirclePoints[{0, -1}, {1.5, 0 Degree}, 4]}] <= 7) ~ 
  Or ~ (Sum[
     EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, pt], {pt, 
      CirclePoints[{0, 1}, {1.5, 0 Degree}, 4]}] <= 7), {x, -6, 
  6}, {y, -6, 6}]`